# Проблема с React-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

При запуске приложения загружается index.html в качестве первой страницы. На этой странице есть `script`, функции которого повешены на нажатие кнопок меню и:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/Login.js"></script>
```

В файле `Login.js` находится `React.Component` `Login`. У этого компонента есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую выполняется следующий код:

```
ReactDOM.render(
            <Verification />,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
```

Этот код сменяет компонент `Login` на компонент `Verification`, функция `render` которого ниже:

```
render()
{
    return (
        <div id="divLoginPanel">
            <form id="formLoginPanel">
                <div className="divLoginPanel_Header">
                    Verification
                </div>
                <div className="divLoginPanel_Container">
                    Тут не важные для вопроса вещи
                    <p>
                        <button className="loginConfirmButton" onClick={this.handleConfirmClicked}>Confirm</button>
                        <button className="loginCancelButton" onClick={this.handleCancelClicked}>Cancel</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Вот функции, повешенные на кнопки:

```
handleConfirmClicked() {
    console.log("In handleConfirmClicked");
}

handleCancelClicked() {
    console.log("In handleCancelClicked");
    /*
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Login/>,
        document.getElementById("container")
    );
    */
}
```

Ну и моя проблема: при нажатии на любую из кнопок Confirm и Cancel все загружается заново. То есть не просто компонент `Verification`, но и вся html-ка, при этом выводится компонент `Login`. Также очищается консоль  и заново выводится то, что выводится в самом начале.

Что не так?

Comment: Вместо смены Login на Verification через ReactDOM.render вам следует использовать условный оператор там, где вы рендерите основное дерево.

Comment: А кнопка надо добавить `return false` в обработчик чтобы они не перезагружали страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию html элемент button имеет атрибут type со значением submit. Именно по этому такое поведение при нажатие. Измените значения type на button.

```html
<button type="button" onClick="...">Button</button>
```

Либо же в обработчике у аргумента Event вызвать метод preventDefault

```js
handleConfirmClicked(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     console.log("In handleConfirmClicked");
}
```

Либо в обработчике в конце выполнить return false

```js
handleConfirmClicked() {
     console.log("In handleConfirmClicked");

     return false;
}
```